# parsing s-expressions using racket

Tags: racket

I'd like to read in a standard racket file and parses the s-expressions in it as a list. For instance given this input:

```
(define y 1)
(define (foo x)
  (+ x 1))
```

it should return: `'("(define y 1)" "(define (foo x) (+ x 1))")`

What would be the easiest way to do so? I was thinking of using `port->string` and friends but that still requires matching up the `)`s. Is there something simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected output is a bit confusing. Why do you want the individual s-expressions as strings? In any case, you probably want [`port->list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._port-~3elist%29%29) or [`file->list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffile..rkt%29._file-~3elist%29%29), which both produce a list of s-expressions. Used on your example input, they produce the following result:

```
'((define y 1) (define (foo x) (+ x 1))
```

If you really do want the individual s-expressions as strings for some reason, you can always convert them back by mapping [`~s`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7es%29%29) over the result, but I’m not sure why such a thing would be useful.

Comment: Thanks. But what would I pass in as `r` for either function? Don't I need to keep track of the parentheses since an s-expr can span multiple lines?

Comment: @JRR The `r` argument is optional, and the default of `read` is what you want. If you’re using `file->list`, just don’t provide the `proc` argument, and if you’re using `port->list`, just pass `read`. It will do all that bookkeeping for you.

Comment: another question: any way that I can teach `read` to ignore the initial `#lang racket` line in the input file? It returns `read: #lang not enabled in the current context` otherwise.

Comment: @JRR Reading *modules* is a pretty different problem from reading files of `read`-able s-expressions, since every `#lang` can have its own parser. (For example, consider `#lang scribble/manual`, which uses a TeX-inpsired syntax rather than traditional s-expressions.) If you want to solve that problem, you’ll probably want different solutions depending on what you intend to actually do with the result. I’d recommend asking another question with more details rather than tacking onto this one.